# stackoverflow error in recursive function

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, stack-overflow

I have the following function is in class implementing a set of numbers as a binary search tree.The function checks if the input integer is in the tree.

```
 public boolean isIn(int v){

     if(root != null){  
        if(v == root.element){
            System.out.print(root.element);
            return true;
        }
        isIn(root.left.element);
        isIn(root.right.element);
       }
       return false;
     }
```

I am getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError** if I check anything other than the first element of the tree with the function.

Edit:
My tree is setup as follows:

```
public class BSTSet{
   private TNode root;

   public BSTSet(){
     root = null;
   }



public BSTSet(int[] input){
     int len = input.length;
      for (int i = 0; i<len-1; i++ ) {
           add(input[i]);
      }

   }

   public void add(int v) {
         if (root == null) {
             root = new TNode( v, null,null);
             return;
         }

         TNode node = root;
         while (true) {
             if (v < node.element) {
                 if (node.left == null) {
                     node.left = new TNode( v, null,null);
                     break;
                 }
                 node = node.left;
             } else if(v>node.element){
                 if (node.right == null) {
                     node.right = new TNode(v, null,null);
                     break;
                 }
                 node = node.right;
             }
             else{
               break;
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: You only ever compare `v` with the `element` value of the `root` node, then you call yourself recursively and do the same comparison. Of course it recurses forever. Re-think what you're doing. The recursive calls have to somehow *advance* through your tree *nodes*.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. How could I possibly traverse through the tree? I tried using the this keyword instead of root but that doesn't work.

Comment: Presumably, `isIn()` is a method of a `Tree` class, and `root` is a field of type `Node`. You have two options: 1) Add a `Node` parameter to the method, so you can call it recursively with a different `Node` to check. 2) Add a `search` method to the `Node` class and make it call itself on the `left` and `right` nodes, so `this` is a different value on every call.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems. You are only every comparing the parameter with `root.element`. Also, `v` is supposed to be the int that the user wants to search for, and you pass in the different elements of the tree, not the value that the user is searching for:

```
isIn(root.left.element);
isIn(root.right.element);
```

Also you are ignoring the result of your recursive calls. You need to rethink your logic a little. You want to be passing a `Node` and an `int` (the search value) to the method. You can have an overloaded method for this:

```
public boolean isIn(int v){
    return isIn(v, root);
}
```

And then have:

```
public boolean isIn(int v, Node node){
    if(node != null){  
        if(v == node.element){
            System.out.print(node.element);
            return true;
        }
        return isIn(v, node.left) || isIn(v, node.right);

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to initialize node somewhere?

Comment: let's say I want to use the function to search this bst, will the method work?

Comment: @Rashik Depends on your BST. Did you try this method with your BST?

Comment: I did, I am getting a null pointer exception for all integers except the first element in the tree.

Comment: @Rashik In the `if` use `if(node != null)`